# Ngx-Indexed-db - Data is not getting saved in Microsoft edge browser, throwing Data Error

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I am using **Ngx-Indexed-db** library for an Angular 8 project. When I am trying to save data into Microsoft Edge browser, IndexDB is throwing **data error**.
In Chrome and Firefox it is working fine.

App.module.ts

```
import { NgxIndexedDBModule, DBConfig } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

  // Ahead of time compiles requires an exported function for factories
export function migrationFactory() {
    // The animal table was added with version 2 but none of the existing tables or data needed
    // to be modified so a migrator for that version is not included.
    return {
      1: (db, transaction) => {
        const store = transaction.objectStore('edit-plan');
        // store.createIndex('planId', 'planId', { unique: true });
      },
      3: (db, transaction) => {
        const store = transaction.objectStore('undo-edit-plan');
        // store.createIndex('country', 'country', { unique: false });
      },
      5: (db, transaction) => {
        const store = transaction.objectStore('plan-header');
        // store.createIndex('country', 'country', { unique: false });
      },
    };
  }

const dbConfig: DBConfig = {
    name: 'MyDb',
    version: 9,
    objectStoresMeta: [{
        store: 'edit-plan',
        storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
        storeSchema: []
    },
    {
      store: 'undo-edit-plan',
      storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
      storeSchema: []
    }, {
      store: 'plan-header',
      storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
      storeSchema: []
    }],
    migrationFactory
};
```

Service File

```
import { NgxIndexedDBService } from 'ngx-indexed-db';
export class IndexedDBService {

  constructor(private dbService: NgxIndexedDBService) {}

  save(obj, curstore) {

    this.dbService.add(curstore, obj).then(() => {
        console.log('data saved successfully');
    },error => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDP3i.jpg).

Comment: At present, I am not sure why it is giving an error while saving the data. I will try to discuss the issue with other senior engineers and try to know their opinion on this issue. If I will get any useful information then I will try to provide it to you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: This an simple example in following link , I will try it to see does it works  in Edge
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db

Comment: "DataError Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements." which means Provided data is inadequate. Base on the error stack, It failed in polyfills.js file. Could you please provide this js files. 
You can also try use the new Edge which have the same core with chrome, You can download form microsoft.com/en-us/edge